# Mulitiple span in single button - Span Positioning

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to span positioning in button but cannot figur it out how to do it. Please help me out. Defferent button acting defferently.

I am using Bootstrap.

My expectation: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36FDj.png)

But Showing:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/97wGP.png)

My Code

```css
.button-row {
        height: 200px;
        width: 180px;
    }
.button-radius {
    border-bottom-right-radius: 2em;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
         box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;  
    white-space:normal;
    word-wrap: break-word;

}

.label-top-left{
    position: relative;
    left: -60px;
    top: -90px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding:20px;
}

.label-top-right{
    position: relative;
    left: 60px;
    top: 90px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding:20px;
}
.label-bottom-right{
    position: relative;
    right: -70px;
    top: 36px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.label-bottom-left{
    position: relative;
    left: -60px;
    top: 90px;
    display: inline-block;   
}
.gi-2x{font-size: 2em;}
.gi-3x{font-size: 3em;}
.gi-4x{font-size: 4em;}
.gi-5x{font-size: 5em;}
```

```html
<h3 class="text-warning">My Purchasing</h3>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 button-container">
                <button type="button" onclick="location.href = 'Purchasing/PurchaseRequisitionRelease.aspx';" class="btn btn-default button-row button-radius">
                    Approve Purchase Requisition 
                    <span runat="server" id="spnPR" class="label label-warning label-top-right">1 Pending</span>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt gi-2x text-warning label-top-left"></span>                    
                </button>
            </div>            
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 button-container">
                <button type="button" onclick="location.href = 'Purchasing/PurchaseOrderRelease.aspx';" class="btn btn-default button-row button-radius">
                    Approve Purchase Order 
                    <span runat="server" id="SpnNoti" class="label label-warning label-bottom-left">2 Notification</span>
                    <span runat="server" id="spnPO" class="label label-warning label-top-right">5 Pending</span>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send gi-2x text-warning label-top-left"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 button-container">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default button-row button-radius" onclick="location.href = 'Purchasing/PurchaseHistory.aspx';">
                    Purchase History                     
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time gi-2x text-warning label-top-left"></span>
                </button>
            </div>            
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this will work...

```css
.button-row {
        height: 200px;
        width: 180px;
    }
.sec1,.sec2,.sec3{
 height: 70px;
    margin: 0 !important;
    margin-top: 8px !important;
}

.button-radius {
    border-bottom-right-radius: 2em;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
         box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;  
    white-space:normal;
    word-wrap: break-word;

}

.label-top-left{
    position: relative;
    left: -60px;
    top: -90px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding:20px;
}

.label-top-right{
    position: relative;
    left: 60px;
    top: 90px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding:20px;
}
.label-bottom-right{
    position: relative;
    right: -70px;
    top: 36px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.label-bottom-left{
    position: relative;
    left: -60px;
    top: 90px;
    display: inline-block;   
}
.gi-2x{font-size: 2em;}
.gi-3x{font-size: 3em;}
.gi-4x{font-size: 4em;}
.gi-5x{font-size: 5em;}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">



<h3 class="text-warning">My Purchasing</h3>
        <div class="row">
                      
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 button-container">
                <a  onclick="location.href = 'Purchasing/PurchaseOrderRelease.aspx';" class="btn btn-default button-row button-radius">
                    <div class="row sec1" >
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send gi-2x text-warning pull-left"></span>     
      <span runat="server" id="spnPO" class="label label-warning pull-right">5 Pending</span>
     </div>
     <div class="sec2">
      Approve Purchase Order 
     </div>
     <div class="row sec3">
      <span runat="server" id="SpnNoti" class="label label-warning pull-left">2 Notification</span>
     </div>
                    
                </a>
            </div>

            </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your hard working and everything is showing good in my local computer. But my hosting site is not showing properly. Please help me: http://mobisap.edifice.consulting/

Comment: In hosting site also, for me displaying correct only. but notifications is not there, because of dynamic content